# Anagrams in java

Tags: java

```java
package intials;

public class Anagrams {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String a = "cat";  
        String b = "act";
        boolean isAnagram = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char c = a.charAt(i);
            isAnagram = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {
                if (b.charAt(j) == c) {
                    isAnagram = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isAnagram) {
                break; 
            }
        }
        if (isAnagram) {
            System.out.println("is anagram");
        } else {
            System.out.println("is not anagram");
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me what is wrong in this code.
Also tell me what should be the changes should I make

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with this code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This code doesn't handle repeated letters. (E.g. it would say that aabc is an anagram of abc).

Comment: I downvoted this question because you do not explain what you are trying to achieve and do not give examples of what is not working.

Answer (score 2):

A easy way to check if two words are anagram is to transform them in array, sort them and compare.

```
    public boolean areAnagram(string str1, string str2) 
    { 
        // Transform strings in arrays
        String[] arr1 = str1.split("");
        String[] arr2 = str2.split(""); 
  
        // Check if they have the same length
        if (arr1.length != arr2.length) 
            return false; 
  
        // Sort array 
        Arrays.sort(arr1); 
        Arrays.sort(arr2); 
   
        // Compare value
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) 
            if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) 
                return false; 
  
        return true; 
    }

    boolean test = areAnagram("toto", "otot");
```

Comment: It would be better to check the length first, then sort `char` arrays retrieved from the input strings with `s.toCharArray()`, also, the case of both strings may need to be equalized.

Answer (score 1):

This is comparatively better for  large characters range :

```
 static boolean isAnagram(String text1, String text2){ 

        if (text1.length() != text2.length()) 
            return false;
        
        // If you want to ignore case sensitivity of characters
        text1 = text1.toLowerCase();
        text2 = text2.toLowerCase();
        
        Set<Character> set1 = new HashSet();
        Set<Character> set2 = new HashSet();

        for (int i = 0; i < text1.length(); i++) {
            set1.add(text1.charAt(i));
            set2.add(text2.charAt(i));
        }
        return set1.equals(set2);
 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the anagrams should have equal lengths, if this condition is not met, the words are not anagrams.

Next, as mentioned in the comments, not only the characters but their frequencies should be compared, that is, a map `Map<Character, Integer>` needs to be created containing frequency of each character in a string.

For one string the frequencies may be counted with `+` sign, and for the other with `-` sign.  If all values in the map are `0`, the words are anagrams.

The implementation may look as follows (using `Map::merge` to calculate frequencies and `Stream::allMatch` to detect the anagram):

```java
    
public static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() != b.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    Map<Character, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0, n = a.length(); i < n; i++) {
        frequencies.merge(Character.toLowerCase(a.charAt(i)),  1, Integer::sum);
        frequencies.merge(Character.toLowerCase(b.charAt(i)), -1, Integer::sum);
    }
    return frequencies.values().stream().allMatch(x -> x == 0);
}
```

Tests

```java
String[][] tests = {
    {"act", "tact"},
    {"acta", "tact"},
    {"Raca", "arca"}
};

for(String[] t : tests) {
    System.out.printf("Are '%s' and '%s' anagrams? %s%n", t[0], t[1], isAnagram(t[0], t[1]));
}
```

Output

```
Are 'act' and 'tact' anagrams? false
Are 'acta' and 'tact' anagrams? false
Are 'Raca' and 'arca' anagrams? true
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is faster with the **time complexity of O(n)**. However, it needs **extra space** for the counting array. **At 256 integers, for ASCII that's not too bad**. *But increasing CHARACTER_RANGE to support multiple-byte character sets such as UTF-8, this would become very memory hungry.* Therefore, it's only really practical when the number of possible characters is in a small range.

```
class Anagram { 
        
    static int CHARACTER_RANGE= 256; 
    
    static boolean isAnagram(String text1, String text2){ 
        
        if (text1.length() != text2.length()) 
            return false; 

        // if want to consider case sensitivity of char
        //char str1[] = text1.toCharArray();
        //char str2[] = text2.toCharArray();
    
        // if don't want to consider case sensitivity of char
        char str1[] = text1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char str2[] = text2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    
        int count1[] = new int[CHARACTER_RANGE]; 
        Arrays.fill(count1, 0); 
    
        int count2[] = new int[CHARACTER_RANGE]; 
        Arrays.fill(count2, 0); 
    
        int i; 
    
        for (i = 0; i < str1.length && i < str2.length; i++) { 
            count1[str1[i]]++; 
            count2[str2[i]]++; 
        } 
                
        for (i = 0; i < CHARACTER_RANGE; i++) 
            if (count1[i] != count2[i]) 
                return false; 
    
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The length should be checked _first_ - no need to compare the contents if the lengths of the words differ,  `Arrays.fill` not needed - when arrays are created they are filled with 0 by default.  Using 256 counters limits the input to ASCII characters only.  Case sensitivity should be taken into account - here `AAa` and `aaA` are not anagrams.  Complexity seems to be O(N) although the length of `count` may significantly exceed the length of input string.

Comment: You just need one count array. Add and subtract on the same array index, that way you can save even more space.